# Remote/Distributed testing using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I followed many sites to do my distributed testing in JMeter but I cannot able to get a result. Can anyone tell step by step process to do distributed testing in jmeter3.0

Comment: What's the environment? Linux or Windows?

Comment: Windows Operating system